# Disable illegal operation dialog boxes

Tags: windows

Is there any way to configure Windows 32-bit not to show dialog boxes when programs have performed illegal operations? I just want them to be killed and not be notified.

I am hoping there is a registry setting for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such setting; that would defeat the purpose of the error messages. Besides, there are multiple different error dialogs caused by different errors from different sources, so there *could* not be a way to disable all of them universally.

Instead, what you can do is to [use a third-party program](http://majorgeeks.com/PTFB_Push_the_Freakin_Button_d4416.html) (eg macro/automation utility) that can detect said dialogs and automatically click the button to dismiss it. You would set up a “window trigger” in the program so that it when a window with the appropriate attributes (eg title, class, etc.) becomes active, one of the macros in the program gets activated and sends a click or keypress to the dialog or one of its controls.

This won’t get rid of the error dialogs altogether, but it can dismiss them fast enough that you won’t even notice them most of the time, except for perhaps the sound.